# css seems only be able to reposition one div after pseudoclass:selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I select multiple div's after the Pseudoselector and it´s selected id to determine the backgroundcolour like this:

```
#Eg1:target + #Eg2, #Eg3{
background-color: blue;}
```

It work's, but when I want to change their positioning like this:

```
#Eg1:target + #Eg2, #Eg3{
bottom: -100%;}
```

...only the first one changes his position after clicking on "Eg1"(I want both to move).

Is there any way to work around this problem without using JavaSript?

(I used multiple other selecting techniques after the pseudo like "~", 
all of the div's are on one and the same level)

Edit:
Of course I defined height width and positioning(they are on fixed) of the div's, I also want them to vanish under the bottom(without any scrollbar)
,sry for my late correction..

Answer (score 0):

did you used position property for these element? without position property "bottom: -100%" will not work. try with "position: absolute" to these property. hope it will work.

Comment: I solved it with mergin Eg2 and 3 into one class (adding the same aside to their id's)

Answer (score 0):

`bottom` property will not work alone. you have to set the positioning of your element to `absolute` or `fixed` in order to have an effect.

use this :

```
#Eg1:target + #Eg2, #Eg3{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
}
```